# Access HTML of an cross-origin iframe in a chrome extension content script via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am working on a chrome extension that collects display ads served on a website for a study. I am trying to access the ad html through jquery as follows:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){   
if(request.todo == "CaptureAds"){
    frames = $('iframe')
    for(var iter=0;iter<frames.length;iter++){
        console.log('==================IFRAME====================')
        console.log('A')
        console.log(frames[iter])
        console.log('B')
        console.log(frames[iter].contentDocument)
        console.log('C')
        console.log(frames[iter].src)
    }
}
```

});

This gives me the following result:

[An cross-origin iframe that I can print but cannot access to the html of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpn8A.png)

[Two normal iframes that I can print and have access to their html as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwJ2G.png)

I have looked up multiple questions on stackoverflow and they lead to the postMessage method. In my case I dont have edit access to the iframe so I can't communicate between the two iframes as suggested in those solutions. Can someone please suggest a way to bypass the same-origin policy in this case without messing with the browser settings.

Here is my manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "xyz",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "abc",
"icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
},
"page_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/get_started16.png",
    "default_popup" : "popup.html",
    "default_title": "example"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.example.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js", "jquery-3.3.1.min.js"],
        "all_frames": true
    }
],
"permissions": ["activeTab","https://www.example.com/*","webNavigation"]
```

}

Comment: Can you share your extension manifest please?

Comment: Broadly, the solution would be to have a content script that your manifest tells to load on every page, including those in frames. Since a content script has access to the DOM of the page it is loaded into, you can access the iframe DOM by exchanging messages with your content scripts.

Comment: added the manifest

Comment: @Utkanos how do  I make it so the same content script loads in all the frames? Also how do I uniquely identify the same content script in the scope of different frames?

Comment: You can Google how to add content scripts in all frames - Google have docs on this. As to how you identify the same content script in different contexts, it comes down to the messages you pass. Give each one an ID and have only certain instaces of the content script respond, depending on what the ID is.

Answer (score 0):

So - the good news is you already have `"all_frames" : true` in your code. You might want to have

```
"matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
```

in your manifest if you want to load this functionality across all of the webpages. For the who's the parent of who part - you'd have to construct a kind of a tree.

Basically your content scripts will be loaded in parent frame as well as the iframe in that frame. You can use the [referrer property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp) and get which URL loaded which page through

```
window.document.referrer
```

and your iframe should be pointing to your parent frame. I don't know your restrictions but I suppose you can figure out what was the parent page (or perhaps you already know?) so it would be a matter of saying *Page A loaded Page B in an iframe*. At that stage your content script is in both of them, so you have access to both of those.

Comment: @ammar075 - I'd appreciate the green tick if it qualifies as the answer.